# Number of trailing zeros in a number

Tags: oracle

I have a column MONTHLY_SPEND in the table with data type of NUMBER. I am trying to write a query which will return number of zeros in the column.
e.g..

```
1000 will return 3
14322 will return 0
1230 will return 1
1254000.65 will return 0
```

I tried using mod operator and 10 but without the expected result. Any help is appreciated. Please note that database is Oracle and we can't create procedure/function.

Comment: what about this value 12005.05? should it return 2 or 3?

Comment: what result expected with this number 2300120?

Comment: 2300120 will return 1 and 12005.05 will return 0. Basically last zeros. I mentioned in the example in the question. We are trying to see if the amount is a round amount and how many zeros at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select nvl(length(regexp_substr(column, '0+$')), 0) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to find

```
create table spend
(Monthly_spend NUMBER);

Begin 
insert into spend values (1000)

insert into spend values (14322)

insert into spend values (1230)

insert into spend values (1254000.65)

End;
```

This query will for this data :

```
select  Monthly_spend,REGEXP_COUNT(Monthly_spend,0)
from spend 
where Monthly_spend not like '%.%' ;
```

if have one more data like 102 and if it should be zero , then try below query:

```
select Monthly_spend,case when substr(Monthly_spend,-1,1)=0 THEN REGEXP_COUNT(Monthly_spend,0) ELSE 0 END from spend;
```

Here is final query for value like 2300120 or 230012000

```
select Monthly_spend,
case when substr(Monthly_spend,-1,1)=0 and REGEXP_COUNT(trim (0 from Monthly_spend),0)<=0 THEN REGEXP_COUNT(Monthly_spend,0) 
 when REGEXP_COUNT(trim (0 from Monthly_spend),0)>0 THEN LENGTH(Monthly_spend) - LENGTH(trim (0 from Monthly_spend))
ELSE 0 END from spend;

Output :

1000        3
1254000.65  0
14322       0
1230        1
102         0
2300120     1
230012000   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, a simple solution.

```
select length(to_char(col1))-length(rtrim(to_char(col1), '0')) no_of_trailing_zeros from dual;


select length(to_char('123.120'))-length(rtrim(to_char('123.120'), '0')) no_of_trailing_zeros from dual;
```

Comment: Why did the Downvote, does it return wrong output, or does it technically wrong.

Comment: think the downvote because in your example zeros are calculated in fractional part as well

Comment: @oreh:  Thats the question, if "1254000.65 will return 0" is true case mean, the question is to include the fractional trailing zeros.

Comment: See the comment by @Sid:  " Basically last zeros", which he/she replied on your comment

Comment: Actually I didn't downvote) and prefer your answer. but think it should be `length(to_char(trunc(123.120)))-length(rtrim(to_char(trunc(123.120)), '0')`

Comment: It's not correct. 1230.01 will return 1 which is not expected

Comment: 1230.01 returning "0", what you expect it should return "1"?